# My SSH tunnels get interrupted because the host machine falls asleep. Bug or Feature?

Tags: bash, ssh, suspend, openssh

My gnome-power preference is set to automatically sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity. Apparently it thinks that a ssh connection is not a valid reason to keep it alive. Is this a feature or a bug? I would like to keep my auto-suspend settings on yet have ssh give it a big fat "No!" when a tunnel is active.

I'm running Natty.

Here is my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent tested this myself - but google revealed this possible answer (article from '[how-to-geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/keep-your-linux-ssh-session-from-disconnecting/)')

You can configure the ssh client to automatically send a protocol no-op code code every number of seconds so that the server won’t disconnect you. This is setting is sometimes referred to as Keep-Alive or Stop-Disconnecting-So-Much in other clients.

Global Configuration

Add the following line to the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

The number is the amount of seconds before the server with send the no-op code.

Current User Configuration

Add the following lines to the ~/.ssh/config file (create if it doesn’t exist)

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Make sure you indent the second line with a space.

Per-Host Configuration

If you only want to enable keep alive for a single server, you can add that into the ~/.ssh/config file with the following syntax:

```
Host *hostname.com
   ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Doesn't mention suspend in there so I'm still a little leery but this will be a great place to start (I was having troubles finding one). Have an upvote, I'll be back to report.